# this object is either const or it is an lvalue; either way we can't sort in place

Tags: c++

The title is cited from *C++ Primer 5th edition*. The code following is from [here](https://github.com/jaege/Cpp-Primer-5th-Exercises/blob/master/ch13/13.56.cpp).

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(std::initializer_list<int> il) : data(il) { }

    Foo sorted() &&;
    Foo sorted() const &;

    void print() const;

private:
    std::vector<int> data;
};

Foo Foo::sorted() && {
    std::cout << "Foo Foo::sorted() &&" << std::endl;
    std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());
    return *this;
}

// this object is either const or it is an lvalue; either way we can't sort in place
Foo Foo::sorted() const & {
  std::cout << "Foo Foo::sorted() &" << std::endl;
  Foo ret(*this);
  std::sort(ret.data.begin(), ret.data.end());
  return ret;
}
```

as for a `const` appearing in the `Foo Foo::sorted() const &`, a copy must be made to `sort` the vector. But why a `&` also prohibit directly use `*this`? To test whether I can use `*this` directly without `const`. I write the following code.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(std::initializer_list<int> il) : data(il) { }

    Foo sorted() &&;
    Foo sorted() &;

    void print() const;

private:
    std::vector<int> data;
};

Foo Foo::sorted() && {
    std::cout << "Foo Foo::sorted() &&" << std::endl;
    std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());
    return *this;
}


Foo Foo::sorted() & {
  std::cout << "Foo Foo::sorted() &" << std::endl;
  std::sort((*this).data.begin(),(*this).data.end());
  return *this;
}

void Foo::print() const {
    std::cout << "<" << this << ">";
    for (const auto &i : data)
        std::cout << " " << i;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Foo f1; f1.print();
    Foo f2 { 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 8, 4, 1, 7 }; f2.print();
    Foo f3 = f2.sorted(); f2.print(); f3.print();
    Foo f4 = Foo({ 2, 6, 5, 3, 8, 4, 1, 7 }).sorted(); f4.print();

    return 0;
}
```

`const` is removed from `Foo sorted() &` and there seems nothing wrong. The authors say that "it is an lvalue; either way we can't sort in place". But if remove const, I sort it. Why the authors say we can't? Is there something I miss or misunderstand what the authors say?

Comment: *"there seems nothing wrong"* - Well, you did modify the function behavior. In one case, the `Foo` original instance is untouched, while in the second it's modified. Could you clarify what you do not understand?

Comment: @Holt Is untouched means we can't change it? If I remove `const`, I did change the instance. The authors say that "it is an lvalue; either way we can't sort in place". But if remove `const`, I sort it. Why the authors say we can't?

Comment: Try to print `f2` at the end.

Comment: If you remove the `const` from that routine as you did, then the object is not const, and it can be sorted in place.  Possibly, the point of the tutorial in the book was to show the effect of `const` methods.

Comment: The `this` pointer is almost-as-if there was a secret parameter, like `void sorted(Foo* this);` on the method.  When `const` is added to the end, it is almost-as-if that secret parameter became `void sorted(Foo const* this);`.